# Will Chromecast device play videos encoded as HLS?

Tags: video-streaming, google-cast

It apparently works on Google TV (for Android apps, not html5 apps), so I'm curious if we'll be able to encode them as HLS (Http Live Streaming) for use with Chromecast?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will now according to the updated SDK docs: 
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

I'm guessing for contentType on MediaInfo you'll pass `application/x-mpegURL`.

Comment: Yep I noticed that when the SDK docs came out yesterday.....that's good news! :)

Comment: hls is working on chromecast but still in beta state

Answer (score 6):

HLS is not yet built into the platform, however support for MPEG DASH, Smooth Streaming and progressive MP4 streaming are there.

UPDATE - THIS WAS THE CORRECT ANSWER AT THE TIME -- IT IS SUPPORTED NOW.

Comment: You say **"HLS is not yet built into the platform..."** which suggests other standards (or HLS at least) will be supported by the Chromecast in future. I have an open bounty question WRT MPEG2-TS support with DASH here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412584/does-chromecast-support-the-ts-container-format-in-mpeg-dash-manifest - can you confirm whether Chromecast currently does or does not support MPEG2-TS or not? Also, if it is not currently supported, is it ever likely to be ? I'll be happy to award the bounty if I can get more concrete details.

Comment: Is there a timeframe for when HLS will be supported?

Comment: This was correct at the time, but it is supported now. :)

Answer (score 3):

According to the new docs it is now supported !

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

Answer (score 1):

No, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/supported_media_types) Chromecast supports two HTTP streaming standards: MPEG-DASH (by the MPEG standards group) and SmoothStreaming (by Microsoft). Looks like Apple's HLS is not supported.

Comment: Is there examples for using mpeg-dash or smooth streaming?  I've tried passing the url to the messagestream loadmedia method and it can't seem to handle either.  Is there a different class/method I should be using?

Comment: Rolf how we can send mp4,m3u8,rtmp,flv urls from iphone to chromecast to play them? Are these format supported by chromecast or is it possible to send these video format urls to chromecast from iphone?