# Does Chromecast allow to stream video directly from Chromecast device or will it go through mobile device

Tags: chromecast

We would like to use Chromecast to stream video SmoothStreaming with Playready from Chromecast device however it would be controled by an Android phone app.

Does streaming go by default through the controling device (such as Airplay for iOS) or always only directly from Chromecast to the source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the content stream from WiFi directly to Chromecast, or from WiFi to Android to Chromecast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875596/does-the-content-stream-from-wifi-directly-to-chromecast-or-from-wifi-to-androi)

Answer (score 2):

It works the other way around - your SmoothStreaming content, protected by PlayReady is requested by the Receiver in the Chromecast device from the Cloud, when requested by your phone / tablet / Chrome Sender.

The content doesn't go through the controlling device.

Comment: Can you make this clear? Do we need custom iPhone app to send url of stream such as mp4, rtmp, m3u8? Or we need custom iphone app and only that custom app should send url of video page not actual stream url? Or all sending media url can be done from iPhone google chrome browser(not considering screen mirroring)?

Comment: As a user of content, you need a developer to have created a Client App that uses the Google Cast API's.  That App will ask that a (generally paired) Receiver App be launched on the Chromecast device.  That Client App can then send a URI of some kind (usually an actual URL) to the Receiver App of some media the user would like displayed on the TV.

Comment: Thanks for reply . But do you think google chromecast will support more video formats in the future? Is it hardware issue that it doesn't support m3u8 stream and other fomats?

Comment: We will support m3u8 in the future.  There is already a SO question on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869492/will-chromecast-device-play-videos-encoded-as-hls

Comment: Is there an working example how PlayReady with SmoothStreaming works? Who gets the license and all the flow?

Currently if I provide playready URL it plays with BLACK video container. I do not get callback of `onKeyRequested(long requestId, String method, String[] requests)` either. Any guidelines will be greatly appreciated :-)